# Inactive Community but still accessible

Tags: community, customer-community, community-cloud

We have a Salesforce community website based on a *Visualforce page*

I go to Community workspace -> Administration -> Settings

then I click deactivate

But the community is still accessible for login and non login users

What is the exact purpose of deactivating a community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the source of this issue

Apparently Salesforce community offers the ability to setup the page to display if the community is `active`/`inactive`

> Setup -> Communities -> Administration -> Pages -> Go to force.com

Then you can change the page to display if the community is active/inactive

[image]